# Using map-reduce to ordering list

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

Have a piece of code like:

```
public class Idea 
{

    (...)
     public IList<IdeaSupporter> Supporters { get; set; }

}

public class IdeaSupporter
{
     (...)
   public int Tokens { get; set; }
}
```

Try to order ideas by supporters tokens. I know i must use map-reduce but i quite new at it. Anyone knows how should using map-reduce in that case correcty looks?

Comment: What's wrong with `Supporters.Sort()`? Do you have hundreds of thousands or even millions of supporters in your list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624384/sorting-large-data-using-mapreduce-hadoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index should look like:

```
from idea in docs.Ideas
select new 
{
  SumOfSupportersTokens = idea.Supporters.Sum(x=>x.Tokens)
}
```

Note that this isn't a map/reduce index, it is a simple map index that outputs the sum.
You can then order on that.

Comment: Thanks! Have two short questions yet: 1)I should add that index on document level ,not in code,right? 2) how can iuse that index in code: `list.OrderByDescending(????)`

Comment: That index cant be saved-error has occured: `error CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type` Any idea how should it looks like?