# MapReduce sorting with heap

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed

I am trying to analyze the social network data which contains `follower` and `followee` pairs. I want to find the **top 10 users** who have the most followees using MapReduce.

I made pairs of `userID` and `number_of_followee` with one MapReduce step.

With this data, however, I am not sure how to sort them in distributed systems.

I am not sure how `priority queue` can be used in either of Mappers and Reducers since they have the distributed data.

Can someone explain me how I can use data structures to sort the massive data?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Google out sorting using mapreduce. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624384/sorting-large-data-using-mapreduce-hadoop

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have big input file (files) of format `user_id = number_of_followers`, simple map-reduce algorithm to find top `N` users is:

1. each mapper processes its own input and finds top N users in its file, writes them to a single reducer
2. single reducer receives `number_of_mappers * N` rows and finds top N users among them

Answer (score 1):

To Sort the data in descending order, you need another `mapreduce` job. The Mapper would emit "number of followers" as key and twitter handle as value.

```
class SortingMap extends Map<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text> {
    private Text value = new Text();
    private LongWritable key = new LongWritable(0);

    @Overwrite
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        // Assuming that the input data is "TweeterId <number of follower>" separated by tab
        String tokens[] = value.split(Pattern.quote("\t"));
        if(tokens.length > 1) {
            key.set(Long.parseLong(tokens[1]));
            value.set(tokens[0]);
            context.write(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

For reducer, use [`IdentityReducer<K,V>`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/IdentityMapper.html)

```
// SortedComparator Class

public class DescendingOrderKeyComparator extends WritableComparator {
    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable w1, WritableComparable w2) {
        return -1 * w1.compareTo(w2);
    }
}
```

In the Driver Class, set `SortedComparator`

```
job.setSortComparatorClass(DescendingOrderKeyComparator.class);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help.